# Angular - Issue with routerLink and state

Tags: angular, angular-routing, routerlink, angular-routerlink

From an html page I want to route to another page using routerLink and state.
With  tag there's no issues, during ngOnInit in landing page, I can retrieve state as expected.
Using  tag home page is navigate as well but state results undefined.

What's my wrong?

**html of login page**

```
<button routerLink="/home" [state]="navExtra.state">
    Go Home Page via button
</button>
<a routerLink="/home" [state]="navExtra.state">Go Home Page via a</a>
```

**ts of login page**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss']
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  navExtra: NavigationExtras = {
    state: { data: { a: 'a', b: 'b' } }
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**ts of home page**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, i do not see `navExtra` defined in your component ts file.

Comment: Sorry my wrong, I don't remeber to paste ts of starting page

Comment: [routerLink]="['/home']" [state]="navExtra.state"

Comment: @ErvinLlojku same issue also with the last correction you have proposed...

Comment: i too experienced this issue with Angular: 8.2.14, seems like [state] directive is only working with "a" tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to pass `state` through a button. If we inspect the source code of `routerLink`, we can see...

when **not** an `a` tag:

```ts
@Directive({selector: ':not(a):not(area)[routerLink]'})
```

`state` isn't included in `extras`:

```ts
@HostListener('click')
onClick(): boolean {
  const extras = {
    skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
    replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
  };
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
  return true;
}
```

> [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.8/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L163)

whereas when we have an `a` tag:

```ts
@Directive({selector: 'a[routerLink],area[routerLink]'})
```

it is included:

```ts
@HostListener('click', [/** .... **/])
onClick(/** .... **/): boolean {
  // .....
  const extras = {
    skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
    replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
    state: this.state // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here!
  };
  this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
  return false;
}
```

> [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.8/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L263)

So your option is to style that link to look like a button, or then call a function on button click which performs the navigation, like presented in other answer, here I kindly refer to that code posted by **AbolfazlR**:

```ts
this.router.navigate(['home'], this.navExtra);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to your desired page with `click event` and set state:

```
<button (click)="test()">Test</button>
```

and test method in your component:

```
test(){
  const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state: {example: 'This is an example'}};
  this.router.navigate(['test'], navigationExtras);
}
```

in the destination you can retrieve data like the following :

```
example:string;
constructor(private router: Router) { 
   const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
   const state = navigation.extras.state as {example: string};
   this.example = state.example;
}
```

[**Stackblitz Here.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bupuzn)

Comment: I know about that, but I'm looking a way to do that from html also from <button> tag and not only fro <a> tag.

Comment: @Xilo - I tried a lot but It did not work ( from Html also from <button> tag); the only method above worked.