# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null

Tags: angular

this is my code and I am getting the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null "

```
  ngOnInit() {
  const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
  const state = navigation.extras.state as {
  api: string;
  trace_id: string;
  token_id: string;
  hotel_code: string;
  result_index: string;
  };
  this.reqObj = {
  api: state.api,
  trace_id: state.trace_id,
  token_id: state.token_id,
  hotel_code: state.hotel_code,
  result_index: state.result_index
    };
  }
```

Comment: Did you try moving the same piece of code to the constructor?

Comment: You can find answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620180/how-to-do-unit-testing-for-getcurrentnavigation-extras-state-in-angular-7

Answer (score 5):

You might need to invoke `getCurrentNavigation()` in the constructor. Also you could define an interface to avoid repeating the object type. Try the following

```js
export interface Hotel {
  api: string;
  trace_id: string;
  token_id: string;
  hotel_code: string;
  result_index: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './details.component.css' ]
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  reqObj: Hotel;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.reqObj = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().navigation.extras.state as Hotel;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: if i set the this.router.getCurrentNavigation().navigation.extras.state as Hotel then how can i pass the value to reqObj

Comment: Becase the variable `reqObj` is also defined of type `Hotel`. Please notice the line `reqObj: Hotel;`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the right Router at constructor? Like:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(public router: Router)
{
    const navigation = router.getCurrentNavigation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `state` is used with `[routerLink]`, it's ignored... ([Angular - Issue with routerLink and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168236/angular-issue-with-routerlink-and-state))

Answer (score 0):

```
data: '';
constructor(public router: Router) {
let data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
if(data)
 this.data = data;
}
```

Check with if statement and your data will be available.

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentNavigation()` can be null and extras can be null also, so it's much safer to do

```
this.successMessage = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state ?? {};
```